# my post method is not working in localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

I m trying to do post some data to php but it is not working and also i  have checked chrome dev tool. That when i click the equal button it will appear this status:
calculation.php 
method:OPTIONS
status:(canceled)
text/plain
jquery.min.js:4 
0 B 
8 ms

I am not sure what is the problem. However it works in here : daciusa.org/pella/calc.html

```
 $(function () {
        var $show = $('#display');
        var currentDisplay = "";

        $show.val(0);


        $(document).on('click', 'button.number', function () {

            if ($show.val().length >= 8) {
                $show.val("Error");
            } else if ($show.val() == "Error") {
                $show.val("0");
            } else if ($.inArray($show.val(), ['+', '-', 'x', '/']) !== -1) {
                var addOp = $show.val();
                if (addOp) memory.push(addOp);
                $show.val($(this).val());
            } else {
                $show.val(($show.val() == "0" ? "" : $show.val()) + $(this).val());

            }
        });
        $("#clear").click(function () {
            $show.val("0");
        });
        $("#ce").click(function () {
            if ($show.val().length >= 2) {
                $show.val($show.val().substring(0, $show.val().length - 1));
            } else {
                $("#ce").trigger("click");
            }
        });
        var memory = [];


        $(document).on('click', 'button.function', function () {
            var addnum = $show.val();
            if (addnum) memory.push(addnum);
            $show.val($(this).val());
        });

        $('#equ').click(function () {


            var addnum = $show.val();
            memory.push(addnum);


            $.post("calculation.php", {
                execute: memory
            }, function (data, status) {
                console.log("Success!!");
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
            $show.val(data);
            var e = memory.join('');
            memory = [];
            });
        });
    });
```

php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['execute']) && is_array($_POST['execute'])) {
    $total = (int)$_POST['execute'][0];
    for($i=1;$i<count($_POST['execute']);$i+=2){
        switch($_POST['execute'][$i]){
            case '+': $total += (int)$_POST['execute'][$i+1];break;
            case '-': $total -= (int)$_POST['execute'][$i+1];break;
            default : $total += (int)$_POST['execute'][$i+1];
        }
    }
    echo $total;
}
else echo 'Error';
?>
```

Comment: And you are sure you have some sort of web server running, such as Apache (xampp for example)?

Comment: no any web server running i guess

Comment: Because PHP is a server sided language, you will need some sort of PHP server running before you can do anything with PHP, as far as I am aware of. Try Apache for example: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: Are you sure the correct url is called on localhost?

Comment: I don't know because i use ajax to post to the php

Comment: I just install xxamp and i don't really know how to use it

Comment: @yoadle Stop trying to deface answers that are posted to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
echo json_encode($total);
```

instead of

```
echo $total;
```

Comment: echo would show the results, so it Data variable in js will have th same value.. @foobar

Answer (score 0):

May be try:

JS

```
$(function () {
var $show = $('#display');
var currentDisplay = "";

$show.val(0);


$(document).on('click', 'button.number', function () {

    if ($show.val().length >= 8) {
        $show.val("Error");
    } else if ($show.val() == "Error") {
        $show.val("0");
    } else if ($.inArray($show.val(), ['+', '-', 'x', '/']) !== -1) {
        var addOp = $show.val();
        if (addOp) memory.push(addOp);
        $show.val($(this).val());
    } else {
        $show.val(($show.val() == "0" ? "" : $show.val()) + $(this).val());

    }
});
$("#clear").click(function () {
    $show.val("0");
});
$("#ce").click(function () {
    if ($show.val().length >= 2) {
        $show.val($show.val().substring(0, $show.val().length - 1));
    } else {
        $("#ce").trigger("click");
    }
});
var memory = [];


$(document).on('click', 'button.function', function () {
    var addnum = $show.val();
    if (addnum) memory.push(addnum);
    $show.val($(this).val());
});

$('#equ').click(function () {


    var addnum = $show.val();
    memory.push(addnum);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "calculation.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{
            execute: memory
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'successful'){
            console.log("Success!!");
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
            $show.val(response.data);
            var e = memory.join('');
            memory = [];
        } else {
            console.log("failed!");
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("failed!");
        console.log(arguments);
    });
});
```

});

PHP

```
<?php
$output = array(
    'status' => 'unsuccessful'
);
if(isset($_POST['execute']) && is_array($_POST['execute'])) {
    $total = (int)$_POST['execute'][0];
    for($i=1;$i<count($_POST['execute']);$i+=2){
        switch($_POST['execute'][$i]){
            case '+': $total += (int)$_POST['execute'][$i+1];break;
            case '-': $total -= (int)$_POST['execute'][$i+1];break;
            default : $total += (int)$_POST['execute'][$i+1];
        }
    }

    $output['status'] = 'successful';
    $output['data'] = $total;
}

header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
```